Does Oracle JDBC Driver support Jakarta XA Transactions?
Is there a version of Oracle JDBC driver that supports Jakarta transactions (using the jakarta.transaction package rather than javax.transaction)?
I'm trying to build an XA, 2 Phase Commit solution using Spring, Hibernate 6.5.2 and Narayana JTA 7.0.1 and don't see anything calling the prepare phase.  In Eclipse, when I looked at the Outline for the Oracle JDBC Driver classes (ojdbc11-21.9.0.0), I noticed that oracle.xa.client.OracleXAConnection.getXAResource() returns a javax.transaction.xa.XAResource and my transactions are behaving like simple transactions (not 2PC, not calling prepare(), etc.)
That got me wondering whether I need support for jakarta.transaction (rather than javax.transaction) since Narayana JTA 7.0.1 uses Jakarta.  In other words, is is possible that my Oracle driver is not participating in a Jakarta XA transaction because it only supports the old Java XA transactions.
